# Fetching data using Psycopg2 module in python

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

While I am trying to run the following basic python script for fetching data in postgresql database using psycopg2 module :

```
cur.execute("""SELECT project from project_tlb""")
rows=cur.fetchall()
print rows[5]
```

the output for above I am getting is

```
('html',)
```

The value inside the table is html which is of type 'text'. Any suggestions how to get only the value html instead of ('html',) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned value `('html',)` is a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) so you can just access its first element:

```
rows[5][0]
```

to get

```
'html'
```